# Trigger After Update SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have `Customer` table. To simplify lets say i have two columns

```
Id  
Name
```

I have a second table (`Log`) that I want to update ONLY when the `Id` column of my customer changes. Yes you heard me right that the primary key (`Id`) will change!

I took a stab but the `NewId` that gets pulled is the first record in the `Customer` table not the updated record

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ID_Modified]
    ON [dbo].[customer]
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF UPDATE (Id) 
     BEGIN
        UPDATE [log]
        SET NewId = Id
        FROM customer
     END
  END
```

Comment: PK changes and triggers are difficult/impossible to get correct. The `inserted` and `deleted` tables contain the rows as they are now and as they were before the statement started. But the usual way that you match up rows between those two tables is *via* the PK. Can you not add a surrogate (unchanging) unique key to this table? It will make writing the trigger far more straightforward.

Comment: Did my suggested answer work for you?  Would you accept the answer so that other users can benefit from knowing that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Many would make the argument that if you are changing PK values, you need to rethink the database/table design.  However, if you need a quick & dirty fix, add a column to the customer table that is unique (and not null).  Use this column to join between the [inserted] and [deleted] tables in your update trigger.  Here's a sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    Id INT CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(128),
    UQColumn INT IDENTITY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_Customer_UQColumn UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Log] (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    LogMsg VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Customer
    (Id, Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Larry'),
    (2, 'Curley'),
    (3, 'Moe')

INSERT INTO dbo.[Log]
    (CustomerId, LogMsg)
VALUES
    (1, 'Larry is cool'),
    (1, 'Larry rocks'),
    (2, 'Curley cracks me up'),
    (3, 'Moe is mean')


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Customer_Upd]
ON [dbo].[customer]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE l
SET CustomerId = i.Id
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d
    ON i.UQColumn = d.UQColumn
JOIN [Log] l
    ON l.CustomerId = d.Id
END

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Log]

UPDATE dbo.Customer
SET Id = 4 
WHERE Id = 1

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Log]
```

Comment: I am unclear why you have Join deleted and inserted when i want perform this trigger only when the ID field is updated (not inserted or deleted)

Comment: @user1287453: The inserted and deleted tables are special tables automatically created by SQL Server for DML triggers.  Theses tables exist for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: @user1287453:  to clarify, within the scope of the UPDATE TRIGGER, the [inserted] table and the [deleted] table both contain the rows that are affected by the UPDATE statement.  [deleted] is the "before" and [inserted] is the "after".  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok i have this working based on your example provided above.  I would like to take this one step further.  The Log file is actually in a different Database (same server though).

Comment: @user1287453:  all you need to do is use the fully qualified name of the log table:

UPDATE l
SET CustomerId = i.Id
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d
    ON i.UQColumn = d.UQColumn
JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Log] l
    ON l.CustomerId = d.Id
END

Please mark my answer as accepted.  Thx!

Comment: @user1287453 - you should avoid attempting *any* form of external access from within a trigger. If you want the data to go into a different database, the trigger should just queue this data locally to go across using e.g. service broker. Triggers shouldn't usually cause the original transaction to abort if, say, the other database (or any other external resource) is temporarily unavailable.